# Which buildings utilize mined resources?

Tags: tropico-4

Can someone give a brief overview which resources can be processed into by which industry building?

I know for example that you can make jewels out of gold in the jewel factory, but what can you do with iron or salt?

Are there resources that are only good for exporting? Which resources are there that you can only get by import?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Car Factories turn **bauxite** into cars. Electronics factories turn it into electronics.
- Canneries turn **coffee**, **fish**, and **pineapple** into canned versions of those products.
- Cigar factories turn **tobacco** into cigars.
- Jewelry Factories convert **gold** into Jewelry and Fine Jewelry.
- Lumber Mills can convert **logs** into lumber. Furniture shops can turn lumber into furniture.
- Oil Refineries convert **crude oil** into refined oil.
- Rum Distilleries convert **sugar** into rum and spiced rum.
- **Salt** cannot be refined, but having a salt mine boosts the production of canneries and ranches.
- Weapons Factories convert **iron** into weapons.

Comment: Bauxite is an ore of Aluminum in real life - is Aluminum in the game? If not, it's probably export only.

Comment: @RavenDreamer: There is no aluminum processing, nor is the material available for import/export.

Comment: Perfect, exactly the answer I was hoping for.